How to get drug label by application number
I'm referring this api docs: https://open.fda.gov/apis/drug/label/how-to-use-the-endpoint/ and this docs for list of searchable fields: https://open.fda.gov/apis/drug/label/searchable-fields/
This is what I came up with after reading docs but somehow its not working.
https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=application_number:NDA008107
Also tried with:
https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?count=openfda.application_number:NDA008107
But none worked.

Based on the following search within the National Drug Directory, there are no drugs with the Application Number you specified; perhaps, the number is incorrect: 

Try search with 008107

@Rahul Just did. Same result: no matches
